# FastCSV file handling fails

Tags: android, csv, file-handling

i am trying to extract some data out of a csv file which looks like this:

```
"Anmeldung";"1576017126809898";"1547126680978123";"";"";"Frau"
"Anmeldung";"1547126680911112";"1547126680978123";"";"";"Frau"
```

my function to read all the data from the file looks like this:

```
private void readAllData() {
    File file = new File(filePath);
    CsvReader csvReader = new CsvReader();
    csvReader.setFieldSeparator(';');
    csvReader.setTextDelimiter('\"');
    csvReader.setContainsHeader(true);
    try {
        CsvContainer csv = csvReader.read(file, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        MainActivity.setCsv(csv);
        MainActivity.setPosStatus(0);
        MainActivity.setPosBookingNumber(1);
        MainActivity.setPosHasTookPart(3);
    }catch (Exception e) {

        showDialogCantReadFile();
    }

}
```

When the App reaches my function the application stops working.
Am I doing something wrong with my file-handling? Or am I using FastCSV wrong

It doesn't even run into the catch. It just stops at the .read methode

Edit:
I am using android 7.1 and I am using following permissions

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Have you ask read and write permission ? before read file from storage.

Comment: Yes, I did. I have the read and write permission in the Manifest

Comment: If you are using  > = lollipop device then you have to ask runtime permission to access  file.

Comment: Do you mean the Read and Write permissions ?

Comment: Yes........ Read and Write permission https://mobikul.com/getting-read-write-permission-external-storage-android/

Comment: @MehulKabaria Yes I already have them in my Manifest

Comment: May want to temporarily switch to `Throwable` to see if its an unchecked exception being thrown somewhere in the call.

Comment: It is necessary to ask runtime permission also even you set it in your Manifest.